# ManyToMany join Not IN

Tags: many-to-many, jpa-2.0

I have these entities:

In my TestType entity:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "testTypes")
 private Set<Test> tests = new HashSet<Test>();
```

In my Test entity

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name="Test_TestType", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "test_id", referencedColumnName = "test_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "testtype_id", referencedColumnName = "testtype_id") })
 @OrderBy("shortName ASC")
 private Set<TestType> testTypes = new HashSet<TestType>();
```

I need to write a query to return all TestTypes not associated to a given Test.

I have this query:

```
@Query("select new org.company.IdValue(d.id, d.name) from TestType d where d.id NOT IN (select t.id from Test_TestType t JOIN t.tests test where test.id != :id)")
```

But, getting the error:  Test_TestType is not mapped.

Ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

JPA queries are done on entities, not on tables. The join table Test_TestType is not an entity, so it cannot be explicitely accessed in a JPA query.

You could try a query like this one (not 100% sure if it works). There should be an additional join on TestType in the subselect, instead of just joining Test_TestType to Test, but this is a normal behavior for JPA queries).

```
@Query("select new org.company.IdValue(d.id, d.name) from TestType d " 
+ "where d.id NOT IN ("
+ "select distinct t.id from TestType t JOIN t.tests test where test.id != :id)")
```